# Make turtle go to a random place on the screen with randint

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How to make the cursor go to a random place on the screen with `randint()` using Python turtle graphics:

```
stars = Turtle()

drawings = [Trees, Moon, BlueSky, NightSky, Sun, Sunset, stars]


def penup():
    for x in drawings:
        x.penup()
penup()

def Stars():
    for x in range(5):
        penup()
        stars.goto((randint(-100,0), randint(0,100)))
        pendown()
        stars.left(36)
        stars.forward(10)
        stars.left(36)
        penup()
Stars()
```

I'm trying to make a program that draws stars at the top of the screen, with random spots to where it goes in the night sky. Could someone help with this `randint()` function? It's not going to a random position and it's acting weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess.  Having both `stars` and `Stars` is risky coding.  You use your `penup()` function as if it's turtle's `penup()` function, which it isn't.  Your code doesn't even draw one star, let alone many.  And the star you're attempting to draw looks more like a pentagon than a star.

Here's a rework of your code that does what you describe:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

def stars():
    for _ in range(20):
        star.penup()
        star.goto(randint(-200, 200), randint(100, 200))
        star.pendown()

        for _ in range(5):
            star.left(144)
            star.forward(10)

screen = Screen()

star = Turtle()
star.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

stars()

star.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```